# How to set the initial value of Flutter autocomplete_textfield

Tags: dart, flutter, material-design

IN my Flutter app I have an input form that uses a Flutter autocomplete_textfield for one field. When creating new entries the form works fine. However, I need to also be able to use the form to edit records. Loading all other fields on the form from the record to be edited is working, I cannot find how to set the initial value of the autocomplete_textfield.

Sid

Comment: You might want to checkout this repo which discusses exactly your question: https://github.com/felixlucien/flutter-autocomplete-textfield/issues/16

Comment: @DK15. thank you that led to a resolution of my problem.

Comment: Glad to know it resolved your question. You may upvote my comment for others to know that this question has been answered.

Answer (score 3):

You can create controller to you Search Field and use it as:
`TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();`
and in init method add:
`_controller.text = 'YOUR_TEXT_HERE';`
also dont forget to add a controller to AutoCompleteTextField:
`AutoCompleteTextField<String>(
controller: _controller,
)`

Answer (score 0):

That's right. It works.

Add `clearOnSubmit: false`, so the value in `_controller.text` is not cleared when submitted if you want to keep it alive, otherwise set it to true to clear the value for a new search.