# How to get edited AutoCompleteTextField value into form data

Tags: android, flutter

Using Flutter I have a form that contains an AutoCompleteTextField, I am trying to get changing of the value of the text field working. The value to be edited is placed into the AutoCompleteTextField when the form is opened using the technique linked to my previous question:

[How to set the initial value of Flutter autocomplete_textfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55092666/how-to-set-the-initial-value-of-flutter-autocomplete-textfield)

Now I find that if I try to change the value of the field the autocompletion appears to work, but the new text does not appear in the form data when the form is submitted, the previous entry remains. I have tried adding the new text to the form data but this does not change the behavior.

The "itemSubmitted" code looks like:

```
        itemSubmitted: (species) {
      setState(() {
        searchTextField.textField.controller.text = species.commonName;
      });
```

The submit method calls validate and save on the form data:

```
  if (_formKey.currentState.validate() == false) {
    return;
  }
  _formKey.currentState.save();
```

What more do I need to do to get the new selection in the AutoCOmpleteTextField updated in the firm data?

*Update:
It appears that if I start with a blank form I am able to search for an entry in the AutoCompleteTextField, save the data to my database (without clearing the form), search for a new value, and the data is correctly placed into the form data each time. This suggests that the initialization of the field when the form is opened is causing the issue.*

Sid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was entirely of my own making, I am using the same code to both create and edit an entry. To differentiate between new and edit I was testing for valid object being passed to the page, my mistake was that when my text search field was updated I was simply checking if there was a valid object had been passed to the page, of course, the new data was in the form data structure and was never being placed into the object being edited.

The solution was to simply first check if there is a valid input object, if there is then a secondary test is made to see if the form data matched the input object, if not the new data is then placed into the input object.